# MySQL Syntax error in NaviCat / OK in the WP editor

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with my query using NaviCat for MySQL.

Using Wordpress wpdatatables generator, I'm able to get the results correctly.

Parsing the same code in NaviCat MySQL, I'm getting syntax error "> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7> Time: 0.02s"

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, datescanned
FROM s1 WHERE client = "myuser" 
and risk = "High"
AND
datescanned IN (
SELECT max(datescanned) 
FROM s1
```

I tried to play with " " , and ' ' but still no go.

My Table

```
myuser     2018-01-06   Medium
myuser     2019-02-16   Medium
myuser     2019-02-16   High
myuser     2019-02-16   Low
myuser     2019-03-01   High
myuser     2019-03-01   High
```

I'm trying to get the count of "High" (in this case 2) for the latest date "2019-03-01" only.

Thanks!
Nathalie

Comment: You appear to be missing a trailing `)` on your query

Comment: ahh stupid mistake... got it now... Thx Nick - Nathalie

Answer (score 0):

In your query  you missed  the closing ), you alos missed  group by datescanned  at the nend ..

but you could use a inner join on subselect instead  of In clause too

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, s1.datescanned
FROM s1 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT max(datescanned) max_date 
FROM s1
) t  ON s1.client = "myuser" 
and s1.risk = "High"
AND s1.datescanned  = t1.max_date
GROUP BY  datescanned
```

or if the result fu subquery is just a single value  you could use equal

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, datescanned
FROM s1 WHERE client = "myuser" 
and risk = "High"
AND  datescanned = (
  SELECT max(datescanned) 
   FROM s1
) 
GROUP BY  datescanned
```